I need to change my label style onClick Vue-chartjs
I am using Chart.js to create a Doughnut chart with Vue.js, and I want to customize the legend items when they are clicked. Specifically, I want to change the color and add a line-through style to the legend item when the corresponding data segment is hidden, and revert the changes when the segment is shown again.
However, the typical approach using generateLabels and onClick does not seem to be working as expected. Despite my efforts, the legend items do not update their styles correctly when clicked.
Using onClick to Toggle Visibility and Update Styles:
I attempted to update the legend item's style within the onClick event handler, but the changes did not take effect.
onClick: (e, legendItem, legend) => {
  const index = legendItem.index;
  const ci = legend.chart;
  const meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(0);
  const value = ci.data.datasets[0].data[index];

  if (meta.data[index].hidden) {
    totalValue.value = roundToTwoDecimals(totalValue.value + value);
  } else {
    totalValue.value = roundToTwoDecimals(totalValue.value - value);
  }

  meta.data[index].hidden = !meta.data[index].hidden;

  // Attempt to update legend item style
  legendItem.fontColor = meta.data[index].hidden ? '#d3d3d3' : '#b9b9b9';
  legendItem.textDecoration = meta.data[index].hidden ? 'line-through' : 'none';

  ci.update();
}

Using generateLabels to Customize Legend Items:
I also tried customizing the legend items using the generateLabels function, but the styles still did not update as expected.
labels: {
  generateLabels: (chart) => {
    const original = ChartJS.defaults.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels;
    const labelsOriginal = original.call(this, chart);
    labelsOriginal.forEach((label) => {
      const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
      if (meta.data[label.index].hidden) {
        label.fontColor = '#d3d3d3';
        label.textDecoration = 'line-through';
      } else {
        label.fontColor = '#b9b9b9';
        label.textDecoration = 'none';
      }
    });
    return labelsOriginal;
  },
  font: {
    size: 14,
    weight: 700,
    family: 'Roboto',
  },
  padding: 14,
  color: "#b9b9b9",
},


Desired Outcome
When a legend item is clicked, I want to:
Hide or show the corresponding data segment in the Doughnut chart.
Change the legend item's font color to #d3d3d3 and apply a line-through style when the segment is hidden.
Revert the legend item's font color to #b9b9b9 and remove the line-through style when the segment is shown.
Current Behavior
The data segment toggles its visibility as expected.
The legend item's style does not update correctly.
Additional Information
Here is the relevant part of my Vue component:
<template>
  <v-card class="mt-4 detailsChart">
    <v-card-text>
      <v-row>
        <Doughnut :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions"></Doughnut>
      </v-row>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-text>
      <p>Total Value: {{ totalValue.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }) }}</p>
    </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as ChartJS, CategoryScale, ArcElement, LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Title, Tooltip, Legend } from 'chart.js'
import { useDetailsStore } from '@/stores/details.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, ArcElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement)

const { gasSalesInfo } = useDetailsStore()

const totalValue = ref(gasSalesInfo.combustiveis.reduce((acc, fuel) => acc + parseFloat(fuel.valor), 0))

const roundToTwoDecimals = (num) => {
  return Math.round((num + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
}

const chartData = ref({
  labels: gasSalesInfo.combustiveis.map(fuel => fuel.sigla),
  datasets: [
    {
      backgroundColor: ['#4A90E2', '#50E3C2', '#F5A623', '#D0021B', '#9B9B9B', '#F8E71C'],
      borderWidth: 2,
      radius: 90,
      borderColor: '#0C0E0DFF',
      data: gasSalesInfo.combustiveis.map(fuel => parseFloat(fuel.valor)),
    }
  ]
})

const chartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        generateLabels: (chart) => {
          const original = ChartJS.defaults.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels;
          const labelsOriginal = original.call(this, chart);
          labelsOriginal.forEach((label) => {
            const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
            if (meta.data[label.index].hidden) {
              label.fontColor = '#d3d3d3';
              label.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            } else {
              label.fontColor = '#b9b9b9';
              label.textDecoration = 'none';
            }
          });
          return labelsOriginal;
        },
        font: {
          size: 14,
          weight: 700,
          family: 'Roboto',
        },
        padding: 14,
        color: "#b9b9b9",
      },
      position: "bottom",
      onClick: (e, legendItem, legend) => {
        const index = legendItem.index;
        const ci = legend.chart;
        const meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(0);
        const value = ci.data.datasets[0].data[index];

        if (meta.data[index].hidden) {
          totalValue.value = roundToTwoDecimals(totalValue.value + value);
        } else {
          totalValue.value = roundToTwoDecimals(totalValue.value - value);
        }

        meta.data[index].hidden = !meta.data[index].hidden;

        // Atualizar a legenda
        const labels = ci.options.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels.call(this, ci);
        ci.legend.legendItems = labels;

        ci.update();
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      bodyFont: {
        size: 13,
        color: "#b9b9b9"
      },
      padding: 10,
      callbacks: {
        label: function (valor) {
          const value = parseFloat(valor.raw).toLocaleString('pt-BR', {
            minimumFractionDigits: 2,
            maximumFractionDigits: 2
          });
          return ` R$: ${value}`;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  layout: {
    padding: {
      top: 8,
      bottom: 10
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.detailsChart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--lbc-background-color-2);
}
</style>

How can I correctly update the style of the legend items in Chart.js when they are clicked, to reflect the hidden or visible state of the corresponding data segments?

I think a hosted [repro] like Stackblitz would be very welcome.

You should use as the generateLabel's original method the doughnut/pie specific generateLabel rather then the generic legend generateLabels. You can find that, for instance, as ChartJS.registry.getController("doughnut").overrides.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels
